# SSAS Deploy fails: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.StructuredDataSource'

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I am trying to deploy an SSAS tabular model in our devops process using the deployment utility: Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Deployment.exe.  I am using the command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Deployment.exe" "Model.asdatabase" /s:ssaslog.log
```

This returns the following error:

> Reading input files...
>   Error loading Model.asdatabase: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.StructuredDataSource' to type 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ProviderDataSource'.

We are using SQL Server 2017.  This is a new tabular instance in 1400 compatibility mode.  The command executes successfully from my workstation deploying to the build server, but throws the error when run from the build server.  Both machines have SQL Server SSAS 2017 installed along with SSDT 2017.

Am I missing something that needs to be installed on the build server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install SQL Server Management Studio 18 and use the Deployment Wizard from there.

I think the 17 version doesn't understand the new Structured Data Source type (PowerQuery data source).